# Jenkins Job to copy files from GIT to windows host

Tags: jenkins

I have to implement a Jenkins job where I access files from a git repository and copy them to a windows server.
I cannot do this via plugins and need to use powershell script.

I have created below script, but its unable to find files from Jenkins workspace. 
How Can I perform this task.

```
Jenkins Job Details:
Freestyle project
SCM - via git repository
Build Triggers: None
Build environement: Use secret text
Bindings: Specified usrname/password variable
Build : Windows power shell
Powershell script:

$loginPassword2 = ConvertTo-SecureString "$($ENV:loginPassword)" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$ENV:loginUsername", $loginPassword2)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName windows_Host_server -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {

Copy-Item .\Solr_config -Destination "E:\install" -recurse -For

}
```

Error:

```
Cannot find path 'C:\Users\****\Documents\Solr_config' because it
 does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\svc_**...nts\Solr_conf 
   ig:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyI 
   temCommand
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you call the PS script from Jenkins job.

Comment: @zett42 added the info about jenkins job